# Total Momentum in the Center of Mass Reference Frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, reference-frames, conservation-laws, collision

For solving problems involving elastic collisions it is useful to use the center of mass reference frame as to avoid quadratic equations. However, I am confused about why the total momentum in the center of mass reference frame is equal to zero. I understand that the change in momentum would be zero, but why is the total momentum equal to zero in this frame?

Comment: That's how the reference frame is defined.

Comment: But why is this the case? Is there some reason this holds true if you move with the center of mass?

Comment: By construction of the center of mass system in our mathematical analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Just call it the center of momentum frame instead and it will seem less mysterious.

If you take the energy-momentum four-vector for each part of the system and add them up, you get a total energy-momentum four-vector. It will be timelike. And in the frame of that vector you get zero total momentum.

It's a useful frame. And calling it the center of mass frame just confuses the issue. Technically the center of mass frame is the center of momentum frame with a specific choice of origin, but an origin hardly matters for anything.

Answer (score 2):

> However, I am confused about why the total momentum in the center of mass reference frame is equal to zero.

The center of mass frame of a system of particles is defined as having two key qualities. Less important is that the center of mass at some time $t_0$ is located at the origin. Much more importantly, the time derivative of the center of mass at that time is the zero vector. It is always possible to define such a frame in both classical mechanics and in quantum mechanics. (Note well: This is not so well definable in general relativity, at least on the scale of the universe. I'll leave that aside.)

**If** no external forces act on a system of particles, and **if** conservation of linear momentum holds true, then by definition, the center of mass of that system of particles moves at a constant velocity. It is extremely convenient to choose a frame in which that constant velocity is zero. The center of mass frame, by definition, satisfies those constraints (assuming those two very big **if**s).

Answer (score 1):

It's best to consult the defining equations. The velocity of the center of mass (in any frame) is defined as

$v_{cm} = \frac{1}{M}(\sum_{i=1}^{n} m_iv_i$)

Therefore $Mv_{cm} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} m_iv_i = P_{tot}$.

The center-of-mass frame is defined as the frame in which the center of mass is at the origin. Therefore, in this frame, $v_{cm} = 0$, by definition. But by the above expression, that means that, in this frame, $P_{tot} = 0$, again, by definition.

So the fact that the momentum is zero in the center-of-mass frame is not some interesting fact that needs explanation. It is just an artifact of how we define this particular inertial reference frame. Albeit often a convenient one.